# IndexOutOfBoundsEception when I've already checked if the arguments are there?

Tags: indexoutofboundsexception, minecraft, bukkit

I am getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException with this code, coding for the Minecraft Bukkit API:

```
if(args.length == 0){
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Wrong syntax. Correct syntax: /mi addpower <Name Identifier of Item> <Power> <EventType>");
        return;
    }

    String displayName = args[0];

    if(args.length == 1){
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Wrong syntax. Correct syntax: /mi addpower <Name Identifier of Item> <Power> <EventType>");
        return;
    }

    //Arg 2 is eventtype
    try {
        eventType = EventType.valueOf(args[1].toUpperCase());
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Such an EventType does not exist!");
        return;
    }

    if(args.length == 2){
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Wrong syntax. Correct syntax: /mi addpower <Name Identifier of Item> <Power> <EventType>");
        return;
    }

    //Arg 2 is power
    Power power = getPower(args[2]);
    if (power == null) {
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "That power does not exist!");
        return;
    }


    Vector<String> a = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(args));
    for(String string : a){
        p.sendMessage(string);
    }
    a.remove(0);
    a.remove(1);
    a.remove(2); //When I try to remove the second element it gives me the exception.
    args = a.toArray(new String[a.size()]);
    power.powerCommand(p, displayName, eventType, args);
```

I do not get why this happens though? I check if the arguments are there and then try to remove them, so how come this error occurs?

Comment: `remove` reduces the count of the collection and therefore the range of valid indices.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`remove` modifies the count of the collection and therefore the range of valid indices.

if `args` has length 3 then

```
Vector<String> a = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(args));
```

creates a vector of length 3 with valid indices 0,1 and 2.

```
a.remove(0);
```

removes the first element and therefore changes the count to `2`. The valid indices are now 0 and 1.

```
a.remove(1);
```

removes the second element of the collection (note this was the third element in `args` not the second). The count of `a` is now 1 so 0 is the only valid index.

```
a.remove(2);
```

throws an exception as the index is out of bounds.

If you want to remove the first three elements you can use:

```
String first = a.remove(0);
String second = a.remove(0);
String third = a.remove(0);
```